# Usage of Interface: Case study

Tags: interface, uml

[image]

From a design point of view, can I say that Interfaces are used to produce flexible code open for future easy maintenance.  Referring to the case study, am I right to say:

Interface in this example is used because both Professor and HeadofDept class have the power to employ people.  Assuming that we might add other people who might be given the right to employ people in the near future.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface will allow your code to call methods like employPeople() on the base type i.e EmployerProfessor. So you pass around EmployerProfessor objects and code need not know what the exact implementation is, it just knows that it can call employPeople(). So it allows for dynamic dispatch of method calls. Using some compiler implementation (vtable etc) it will call the correct method for you.

Interfaces are not always so flexible, its difficult to go and just change an interface since current code in the wild may be affected. An interface provides a contract, it tells the class implementing it, that you must provide the following methods.